# How to redirect Octave's console output to a separate console?

Tags: octave

If I have a function that displays a large amount of output, is there a way to display it all in the terminal separately (maybe using `more` or `less`), such that, upon exiting the pager, I get the Octave's console as is?

Like so:

```
octave:159> retVal = func_with_lotsa_output();
octave:160>
```

I seem to remember a previous version of Octave doing that by default (I'm currently on 3.8.1). Right now, the output is displayed before getting the prompt at line 160 (in between 159 and 160, that is).

I tried fiddling with `PAGER`, but to no avail.

EDIT: I've tried `PAGER("more"), PAGER("less"), PAGER("pg")`. I am unsure of what flags to try in `PAGER_FLAGS()`. Nothing has made a difference.

Comment: Your func_with_lotsa_output creates the output with disp/printf or just no semicolon after the calculations? I don't really understand your question: how do you want more or less and what is "exiting the displayed output"?

Comment: @Andy The function creates an output using `disp`, and I do want to see it, just not in the same screen. When I exit the pager, I don't want to see the pager's output lying there. Or alternatively, the pager should not put its output on the main console.

Answer (score 0):

> "When I exit the pager, I don't want to see the pager's output lying there."

Either your pager is broken, or you just need to activate the pager, with

```
page_screen_output(true)
```

or equivalently

```
more on
```

which, according to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html),

> Turn output pagination on or off. Without an argument, `more` toggles the current state. The current state can be determined via `page_screen_output`.

If it still does not work, try with the "less" pager:

```
PAGER("less")
```

Comment: I tried all of these, and `PAGER("pg")` too. All of them collect and throw the output right at the Octave console. I wonder if there's some pager flags that'd make it so, but I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Comment: Also, @ederag I have Octave 3.2 on another system, which has `PAGER()` value as "pager", and no flags (?). That works well. I'm starting to think that there's something wrong with the pager itself. But other things like `man` commands work fine on a regular terminal.

Comment: @a-Jays You did not mention trying "all these" in your question... Maybe your function output is smaller than one screen ? Please try `rand(50)` if your screen has less than 50 lines. Does it page correctly ? If yes, than as a workaround, you could add some dummy lines to your function output.

Comment: I admit to having left some details out when I said I've tried fiddling with `PAGER`. That's only because I am unsure of the correctness, or even usefulness of what I tried. Also, the size of function output makes no difference to it. It just _always_ puts its output right there- which is what puzzles me, since in the Octave 3.2 I have, it _always_ works correct.